# testacular: how to test angular.js directive

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I know how to use jasmine to do test, but how to use the jasmined based `testacular` to test directive, suppose I have defined a directive like this:

```
angular.module('todoList', [], function () {

}).directive('dt', function ($compile) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        template: '<p ng-click="test()">HaHaHa</p>',
        replace: true,
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.test = function () {
                console.warn('click!');
            }
        },
        link: function ($scope, $el, $attr) {
            var checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" >';
            $el.append($compile(checkbox)($scope)); 
        }
    }

})
```

how can I test the `dt` element?

I have find some tutorial and try to write the test in this way:

```
describe('My own function', function(){
    it('should get called on a click', inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        element = $compile('<div dt></div>')($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();
        browserTrigger(element, 'click');
    }));
});
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: You don't use any `expect` blocks; how do you know it's not working?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller : it tell me:`FAILED My own function encountered a declaration exception`

Comment: That means an exception/error is being thrown by a function in the `describe` block. Is `element` declared? Also try passing a jqLite instance to `$compile` instead of a string. Otherwise, post a Plunker; there's not enough to go on here.